# read file from jar in spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-io

I am using Spring boot 2.0.4, trying read a json file which is placed in resources/ directory, but getting the 'FileNotFoundException'.

I have referred a lot of pages from Stackoverflow, and other links, but no success so far.

Following is the stack trace snippet, I am not sure why there is '!' in the classpath:

```
/opt/springboot/myProject.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/schema/jsonValidationSchema.json at o.s.u.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217) at o.s.u.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:180)
```

This is the code snippet:

```
        InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("jsonValidationSchema.json").getInputStream();
        JsonNode schemaJsonNode = JsonLoader.fromReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        JsonSchema schemaNode = ValidationUtils.getSchemaNode(schemaJsonNode);
```

References:

[File inside jar is not visible for spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876836/file-inside-jar-is-not-visible-for-spring)

[Read file from resources folder in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot/50654468)

https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/

[java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource cannot be opened because it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863382/java-io-filenotfoundexception-class-path-resource-cannot-be-opened-because-it-d/51100124)

[java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106591/java-io-filenotfoundexception-class-path-resource)

Comment: here it is you can use this. I had same error too. -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225276/1184571

Comment: The exclamation point is to indicate that the location is inside the jar and not part of the file system.